# Logstash (EACCESS) Permission Denied

Tags: logstash

My logstash instance has stopped working with a Permission denied error. I'm running on Windows. I've been using version 7.8.1 and have also tried with 7.16.2. Both return the same error. I'm running as an administrator. Same error in Windows cmd and git bash shells. Same error when I try to run the command on different logstash configuration files.

My command: `logstash -tf logstash-sample.conf`

Error message and stack trace for v7.16.2:

```
Using JAVA_HOME defined java: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_331
WARNING: Using JAVA_HOME while Logstash distribution comes with a bundled JDK.
DEPRECATION: The use of JAVA_HOME is now deprecated and will be removed starting from 8.0. Please configure LS_JAVA_HOME instead.
[FATAL] 2022-05-02 18:08:05.960 [main] Logstash - Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (EACCES) Permission denied - NUL
org.jruby.exceptions.SystemCallError: (EACCES) Permission denied - NUL
        at org.jruby.RubyIO.sysopen(org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1237) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.20.1.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyFile.initialize(org/jruby/RubyFile.java:365) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.20.1.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyIO.open(org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1156) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.20.1.jar:?]
        at uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.rubygems.user_interaction.initialize(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:645) ~[?:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_2_dot_2_dot_33.lib.bundler.ui.rg_proxy.initialize(C:/apps/logstash/logstash-7.16.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/ui/rg_proxy.rb:11) ~[?:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_2_dot_2_dot_33.lib.bundler.ui=(C:/apps/logstash/logstash-7.16.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler.rb:90) ~[?:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_2_dot_2_dot_33.lib.bundler.ui(C:/apps/logstash/logstash-7.16.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler.rb:86) ~[?:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_2_dot_2_dot_33.lib.bundler.rubygems_integration.validate(C:/apps/logstash/logstash-7.16.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:72) ~[?:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_2_dot_2_dot_33.lib.bundler.source.path.validate_spec(C:/apps/logstash/logstash-7.16.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:168) ~[?:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_2_dot_2_dot_33.lib.bundler.source.path.load_spec_files(C:/apps/logstash/logstash-7.16.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:182) ~[?:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1821) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.20.1.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_2_dot_2_dot_33.lib.bundler.source.path.load_spec_files(C:/apps/logstash/logstash-7.16.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:176) ~[?:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_2_dot_2_dot_33.lib.bundler.source.path.local_specs(C:/apps/logstash/logstash-7.16.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:107) ~[?:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_2_dot_2_dot_33.lib.bundler.source.path.specs(C:/apps/logstash/logstash-7.16.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:115) ~[?:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_2_dot_2_dot_33.lib.bundler.definition.specs_for_source_changed?(C:/apps/logstash/logstash-7.16.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/definition.rb:557) ~[?:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_2_dot_2_dot_33.lib.bundler.definition.specs_changed?(C:/apps/logstash/logstash-7.16.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/definition.rb:542) ~[?:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_2_dot_2_dot_33.lib.bundler.definition.converge_paths(C:/apps/logstash/logstash-7.16.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/definition.rb:586) ~[?:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyArray.any?(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:4553) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.20.1.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_2_dot_2_dot_33.lib.bundler.definition.converge_paths(C:/apps/logstash/logstash-7.16.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/definition.rb:585) ~[?:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_2_dot_2_dot_33.lib.bundler.definition.initialize(C:/apps/logstash/logstash-7.16.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/definition.rb:128) ~[?:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_2_dot_2_dot_33.lib.bundler.dsl.to_definition(C:/apps/logstash/logstash-7.16.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:221) ~[?:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_2_dot_2_dot_33.lib.bundler.dsl.evaluate(C:/apps/logstash/logstash-7.16.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:13) ~[?:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_2_dot_2_dot_33.lib.bundler.definition.build(C:/apps/logstash/logstash-7.16.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler/definition.rb:33) ~[?:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_2_dot_2_dot_33.lib.bundler.definition(C:/apps/logstash/logstash-7.16.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler.rb:196) ~[?:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.bundler_minus_2_dot_2_dot_33.lib.bundler.setup(C:/apps/logstash/logstash-7.16.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.33/lib/bundler.rb:144) ~[?:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.lib.bootstrap.bundler.setup!(C:/apps/logstash/logstash-7.16.2/lib/bootstrap/bundler.rb:79) ~[?:?]
        at C_3a_.apps.logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_16_dot_2.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(C:\apps\logstash\logstash-7.16.2\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:89) ~[?:?]
```

I'm not sure what to look at to fix the permission issue. Any ideas on the underlying cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/14042) in logstash. The underlying Java issue is [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8285445). You can make it work with a current JVM by adding `-Djdk.io.File.enableADS=true` to the JVM options.

Comment: This fixed it. I went back to logstash 7.8.1. Added the JVM option you have to the config/jvm.options file and logstash is running again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but mine would work if I try an older JDK released around Feb 2022.